# MongoMapper docs

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

Does anyone have a good resource for MongoMapper documentation? I've been reading through the mongoDB docs, but a lot of it doesn't convert across to ruby/mm. I've been trying to figure out how to do a `SELECT FROM WHERE EXISTS` with little success.

`db.things.find( { a : { $exists : true } } ); // return object if a is present`

The only docs I've found so far [these](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/jherdman/mongomapper/blob/0f131d10d2c7d8b55d82e474d9dddcb3c26d9bb9/MongoMapper/Document/ClassMethods.html#find-instance_method) which have helped a little.

Thanks.

Comment: realted 
http://stackoverflow.com/q/3551990/394449

Answer (score 4):

Here is the three good pdf link which will guide you how to store files,retrieve files,twitter schema,followers, insert,update and many more..........

[First Pdf - MongoDb by Kristina](http://files.meetup.com/930480/MongoDB.pdf)

[MongoDb by Kyle](https://nosqleast.com/2009/slides/banker-mongodb.pdf)

[MongoDb by Mathias Stearn](http://nosqlberlin.de/slides/NoSQLBerlin-MongoDB.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's a documentation project now:  http://mongomapper.com/documentation/