# Mongomapper documentation?

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper, mongoid

I have stumbled upon Mongoid which has great documentation: http://mongoid.org/docs/associations/

But I have heard that MongomMapper is de-facto for Rails.

Where do I find API documentation for using Mongomapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard answer from the author of MongoMapper is that the project is still young and that the API is still in flux.  Download the latest version from Git and look at the tests.  You should be able to get a fair idea of what is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's up on rdoc.info now: http://rdoc.info/github/jnunemaker/mongomapper

Answer (score 0):

MongoMapper now has documentation on http://mongomapper.com